# About shift operator in C++

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am looking at big code base in C++. There is line mentioned as below

```
int capacity( ) const
{
    return ( 1 << theTrees.size( ) ) - 1;
}
```

Here theTrees is

```
vector<int> theTrees
```

What is statement `1 << theTrees.size( )` likely trying to achieve? Assume we have tree size of 25 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A left shift by n is basically multiplying by 2 to the nth power.  Whenever you have `1 << n` you're just calculating the nth power of 2.  E.g.:

```
1 << 0 = 1
1 << 1 = 2
1 << 2 = 4
1 << 3 = 8
```

Etc.

I suspect `theTrees.size()` returns not the number of elements in the tree but the height of the tree (number of levels), because that's the only way this makes sense.  Given a full binary tree, the number of nodes is 2^N - 1, where N is the height of the tree.  E.g., a tree with three levels (n = 3) can hold 2^3 - 1 = 7 nodes.  Check it: The first level has one, the second has two and the third has four.  1 + 2 + 4 = 7.

Comment: Probably a stupid question with an obvious answer, but right shifting would then be dividing by 2 to nth?

Comment: Yup, and shuddering to use Wikipedia for tech info: "Shifting right by n bits on a two's complement signed binary number has the effect of dividing it by 2n, but it always rounds down (towards negative infinity)." from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift.  Knowing the rounding is important :) Also I think 1>>1 = 0, but its been a while.

Answer (score 6):

If your question is about C++: `1<<` is usually thought of as "2 to the *N*th power."

If your question is about data structures theory: a binary tree of height *n* has up to *2^i* nodes per level, for up to *2^n - 1* nodes total. 
(but you should have tagged it that way)

Comment: i am not getting why in getting capacity we are doing 2 to power of Nth. Here theTrees is vector<int> theTrees

Comment: @venkysmarty a binary tree of height *n* has up to *2^i* nodes per level, for up to *2^n-1* nodes total.

Answer (score 2):

In binary, 1 is:

```
1
```

If we shift it left by one, `1 << 1` then we have:

```
10
```

Which is decimal `2`. So shifting `<< 25` means we get:

```
10000000000000000000000000
```

Which is:

```
33554432
```

Similar to how in decimal if we shift left by one, we multiply by 10, doing so in binary multiplies by 2. So we get 2^25 essentially.

Answer (score 2):

It computes two to the power of `theTree.size()` minus 1

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case the size is actually the number of levels. Assuming you have a balanced binary tree this is the number of elements in the tree (if its full). For example a tree with only the head has `1 << 1 -1 = 1` possible nodes where as a full tree with 3 levels has `1 << 3 - 1 = 7` nodes (the head its two children and the children's four children)